# Response.Redirect problem in some Nokia phones

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I'm developing asp.net application for mobile devices. I'm using Response.Redirect in most of the page. The problem I'm having here is some of the old nokia models always have a pop up warning message asking to confirm sending data to a different site if I try to redirect to another page. And when it hits the redirected page, the IsPostback property is true even it is the first load for some reason. This is quite annoying that I can't implement any logic for the first page load. 
If I use Server.Transfer,the warning message won't come out and everything works fine, however, I have some other reason not to use Server.Transfer.
Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

We built a WAP site a few years ago (4 or 5. I think) and found out that the only way to make it work (without the warning) on those old Nokia phones that is to avoid Response.Redirect.

Avoid using ASP.NET forms altogether and write HTML like in the ASP days (do not use ViewState, post to other page, use request parameters as much as possible.